# Change the position of rows in a 2d array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

I want to change a 2d array
`a = [[1,2,3]
     [3,4,5]
     [6,7,8]
     [9,10,11]]`
into

```
b= [[9,10,11]
[6,7,8]
[3,4,5]
[1,2,3]]
```

using numpy package

Comment: .. `numpy.flipud`?

Comment: or `a[::-1, :]`?

Comment: Also, those are python lists, not numpy  arrays...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like task for [numpy.flip](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html), that is:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[9,10,11]])
b = np.flip(a,0)
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[[ 9 10 11]
 [ 6  7  8]
 [ 3  4  5]
 [ 1  2  3]]
```